# Yargs: Call existing command in command handler

Tags: node.js, yargs

I'm trying to implement a `restart` command using yargs. I already implemented the `start` and `stop` commands and all I want to do now, is call these existing commands inside the `restart` command.

Unfortunately it does not work by simply using `yargs.parse('stop');`

```
yargs.command('start', '', () => {}, (argv) => {
    console.log('Starting');
});

yargs.command('stop', '', () => {}, (argv) => {
    console.log('Stopping');
});

yargs.command('restart', 'description', () => {}, (argv) => {
    yargs.parse('stop');
    yargs.parse('start');
});
```

I also couldn't find anything related in the Github issues or the API documentation. What am I missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can simple use JS:

```
function start(argv) {
  console.log('Starting');
}
function stop(argv) {
  console.log('Stopping');
}

yargs.command('start', '', () => {}, start);

yargs.command('stop', '', () => {}, stop);

yargs.command('restart', 'description', () => {}, (argv) => {
   start(argv);
   stop(argv);
});
```

From a brief look at `yargs` API, I don't see another way of doing this.